# Is isNaN() safe to coerce uuid in javascript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, uuid

I am wondering if it is safe to test uuid with the [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) function.

Is it possible that a uuid accidentally returns false when ran through isNaN()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, by UUID, you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), then `isNaN` will do some unexpected things.

(Copied from the console in Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m)

```
isNaN("550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000");
true
Number.isNaN("550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000")
false
```

You should look at these docs:

- [`window.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) - Broken
- [`Number.isNan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) - ECMAScript 6

Comment: In the console I get this:
Number("550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000") ->
NaN . Doesn't it mean Number.isNaN is broken?